# How do I access this javascript object and log it

Tags: javascript, sqlite, google-chrome-console

I have been developing an app with ionic. And I have used SQLite. I have executed a query but I can't console log the value. Here's the code snippet:

```
var query = "SELECT SUM(total) FROM items";
            console.log(query);
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function (res) {

                console.log(res.rows[0]);
                $scope.grand = {};
                $scope.grand = res.rows[0];

                console.log($scope.grand.SUM);

            }, function (err) {
                console.error("error=>" + err);
            });
```

I want to directly console log the value of SUM(total). But, the log shows like below:

```
 Object {SUM(total): 400}
    SUM(total):400
```

How do I directly console log 400?

Comment: `console.log(res.rows[0]['SUM(total)']);`

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it should work like this:

```
console.log(res.rows[0]['SUM(total)']);
```

Because I always feel uncomfortable using characters like parentheses in a key name I would maybe prefer:

```
var query = "SELECT SUM(total) as mytotal FROM items";
```

and then:

```
console.log(res.rows[0]['mytotal']);
```

or

```
console.log(res.rows[0].mytotal);
```